# error while running a c#script inside soundforge

Tags: c#, linq, audio

i am trying to run a c# script inside the soundforge script editor but it is not supporting system.Linq.... here is the error enclosed.. any help in this regard is appreciated..thank you

Compiler error 0x80004005 on Line 23,14 : The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: `using System.Linq` - is this what you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing how SoundForge (up to 10) only requires .NET 2.0, it seems very plausible it runs script in the same environment. That version of .NET doesn't support LINQ, so that would imply you are out of luck.